# Why does this file terminates on \maketitle?

Tags: errors, titles

I have a template LaTeX file from ACM conferences but it gets terminated on \maketitle. Does it have something to do with the fonts? or do you have any solution?

It also gives other errors when you remove \maketitle

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(E:/0_ACMLAtex/Samples/sample-sigconf.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\acmart\acmart.cls"
Document Class: acmart 2017/08/31 v1.47 Typesetting articles for Association of
 Computing Machinery
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls"
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\microtype\microtype-pdftex.def")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\microtype\microtype.cfg"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\oberdiek\refcount.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\totpages\totpages.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\environ\environ.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\trimspaces\trimspaces.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\hyperref\puenc.def")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\url\url.sty"))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\ncctools\manyfoot.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\ncctools\nccfoots.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\iftex\iftex.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\pdftex\glyphtounicode.tex")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\cmap\cmap.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\mweights\mweights.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\fontaxes\fontaxes.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\libertine\LinLibertine_I.tex"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\inconsolata\zi4.sty"
`inconsolata-zi4' v1.112, 2017/01/04 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\newtxmath.sty"
`newtxmath' v1.527, 2017/09/11 Math macros based on txfonts (msharpe)
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\binhex\binhex.tex"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def")<<t1.cmap>>)
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\float\float.sty")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\comment\comment.sty"
Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'CCSXML'
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty")
Special comment 'acks'
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\libertine\t1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd"))
Excluding comment 'screenonly' Include comment 'printonly'
Include comment 'anonsuppress'
No file sample-sigconf.aux.
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\omlnxlmi.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\untxexa.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\lmsntxsy.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\lmxntxexx.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\libertine\ot1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd")<<ot1.
cmap>><<oml.cmap>> ("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\untxmia.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\untxsym.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\newtx\untxsyc.fd")
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty")
Excluding 'CCSXML' comment.
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\libertine\t1linuxbiolinumt-tlf.fd")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\microtype\mt-msa.cfg")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\microtype\mt-msb.cfg")
("F:\Program Files\Protex\tex\latex\libertine\ts1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd")
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...pring Training, 2010.} \Description 
                                                  {Enjoying the baseball gam...
l.231 \maketitle
                
?
```

You can download the file here: https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Please make sure your question make sense to others? How should we know what you're doing when the only thing you provide is the error message. Please provide minimal (but complete) code that for you give this issue and that others can copy and test as is. If the code uses a non-standard class please also provide a link to that class.

Comment: My guess is that you have an outdated version of `acmart.cls`, but the information you provide is not sufficient to make a full diagnosis.

Comment: @daleif Hi I am very new to LaTeX. So, I have no idea what this class is but I provided the link where the file can be downloaded. But regarding the code, I will modify it and past the entire code in a second.

Comment: @egreg I just downloaded from the ACM website: https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart-master.zip

it says something about installing Libertine but I really don't know how to do that!

Comment: it also gives other errors when you remove the make title part. I normally don't have problems with IEEE tex files, they are ready to use but this one is a hell of problems I guess

Comment: @Fzm --- I don't think that is related to the problem. The `acmart` class file linked in your question is dated September 2020. Your log file gives the date as August 2017. Update to the latest class file and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: You have a largely outdated MiKTeX. Update it to begin with.

Comment: @egreg how should i do that ? i mean it's two years old :D I guess it's texworks not miketex

Comment: @Fzm --- you could try downloading and installing [the latest version of MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/download).

Comment: I have something names console, can i update it through that? does it also work on this texworks thing?

Comment: @IanThompson so it solved my problem. I updated the Latex through Console and it is solved now. Thank you for your help. How can I mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was solved by a software update.

Answer (score 0):

@IanThompson gave me a solution and it was literally it. You can either manually download the latest version or you can use the MiKTeX console to automatically update it. I did the latter and it solved the problem. to find the MiKTeX console, try to search your start bar by typing "MiKTeX console".